# Irreducibility of $x^p-x-c$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Exercise from Hungerford's *Algebra,* Page 166, Exercise 8:

> (a) Let $c$ be an element of a field $F$ of characteristic $p$ ($p$ prime). Then $x^p-x-c$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $x^p-x-c$ has no root in $F$.
>
> (b) If $\operatorname{char}F = 0$, then part (a) is false.

I don't understand why it is false when $\operatorname{char}F = 0$. What is an example of such a field?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking: the claim there is true . For any polynomial $\;p(x)\in F[x],\,\,F\;$ any field,  of degree less than four, it is reducible over $\;F\;$ iff it has a root in $\;F\;$ .

Comment: But if the polynomial is of degree larger than 4?

Comment: The book says the proposition does not necessarily hold in field of characteristic 0. I need a counter  example.

Comment: Right, I missed that the degree isn't necessarily less than four.

Comment: The proposition is true for characteristic p( by Artin-Schreier), but I don't know why it is false for characteristic 0.

Comment: I can't think of any counterexample of the precisely exact form you want.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741121/exhibit-a-polynomial-of-the-form-xp-x-c-in-a-field-of-characteristic-0) one can find this example: $x^5-x+15=(x^2+x+3) (x^3-x^2-2 x+5) \in \mathbb Q[x]$.